# Angular 6 proxy.conf.json on apache not working

Tags: angular

I created a project on Angular 6 and setup proxy.conf.json like this:

```
{
    "/test-service": {
        "target": "http://myhost:8080/test-service/",
        "secure": true,
        "pathRewrite": {
            "^/test-service": ""
        },
        "logLevel": "debug",
        "changeOrigin": true
    }
}
```

And on my pc is running like charm. But when i do:

```
ng build --prod --optimization=false
```

And copy builded files to the server ( apache2 /var/www/html) 
the proxy pass is not working
I tried to configure apache proxy pass :

```
ProxyPass /test-service/    http://localhost:8080/test-service/
ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:8080/test-service/  /test-service/
```

but still no luck.

Do i need to change some apache config or to somehow include proxy.conf.json to the build?

Comment: Does it work in normal dev mode? It seems like you should drop the `'test-service'` path at the `"target"` field, so it proxies straight to your server at `http://myhost:8080`

Comment: Yes it is working on normal dev mode. I tried to remove this but it still return me http status 404 not found

Comment: Ahh wait. the `proxy.conf ` is not even included in the production build. Production builds require a different setup of configurations

Comment: Can you explain me what type of setup is require? Or post me tutorial?

Comment: I added some more details about the procedures, keep me posted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

proxy.conf.json is not included in the production files and therefore requires a different kind of setup.

Two approches may be:

1. Include the newly created production files within the server 'public' folder so it serves them as the UI for the server.

   in express:

   `app.use('/', express.static(path.join(__dirname, './path/to/client/build/files')))`;
2. Serve the Front UI separated from the server, while ALLOWING CORS specifically pointing the **Client origin** (ex: `localhost:4200` or `www.example.com`) and MAKING SURE the API calls point to the server you built. this can be done dynamically with `environment` variable which serves different values according to serve mode (prod : true/false); When build --prod is used, `environment.prod.ts` values are used
   then you will need to include the environment.APIEndpoint in all of your API call strings (ex: `this.http.get(environment.APIEndpoint + '/route/somewhere')`

To keep using proxy.conf.json for dev and also preparing for prod:

In dev mode: `environment.APIEndpoint = 'test-service'`

In prod mode: `environment.APIEndpoint = 'https://www.example.com/api' (or https://api.example.com')`

Comment: I manage to fix the problem. As Omer Shukar said proxy.conf is not included in build for prod. To fix that i added BASE_URL new constant that is directly pointing to the apache on the server. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Awesome! glad to have helped :-)